# WSO2 EI611 FTP url for inboundendpoint FILE invalid, throws error

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

> [2017-10-31 18:38:43,008] [] ERROR - FilePollingConsumer Repeatedly
>   failed to resolve the file URI:
>   ftp://username":***@"servername/folder/folder/folder/
>   org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException: Invalid absolute URI
>   "ftp://username":***@"servername/folder/folder/folder/".
>
> Caused by: org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException: Expecting / to
>   follow the hostname in URI
>   "ftp://username":***@"servername/folder/folder/folder/".

Tried several options, still not working. I used FTP url syntax/format from previous StackOverflow WSO2 postings and product documentation, but did not work. what am I doing stupid?

Comment: Ok, I found the error is because of special character "@" in the password. Now this error disappeared, but new error : 2017-10-31 21:29:55,356 [-] [pool-29-thread-1]  WARN FilePollingConsumer Unable to access or read file or directory :  ftp://username":@"servername/folder1/folder2/folder3/. Reason: The file does not exists!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding `vfs.passive=true` in the FTP URL did the magic. FTP inbound endpoint works fine.